# MongoError: server localhost:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Data to save**

```
{ _id: 56083f1b9a1b20d88c3c3e05,
  mayfield: false,
  postponed: false,
  venue_id: null,
  venue: null,
  result: [ null ],
  league_id: null,
  away_id: null,
  home_id: null }
{ _id: 56083f1b9a1b20d88c3c3e06,
  mayfield: false,
  postponed: false,
  venue_id: null,
  venue: null,
  result: [ null ],
  league_id: null,
  away_id: null,
  home_id: null }
```

**Code**

```
var Games = mongoose.model('Games');
var result = new Games();

result.save(function (err, saveData) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    return result;
});
```

**Error thrown**

```
MongoError: server localhost:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}
    at null.<anonymous> (c:\var\www\beta.com\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:251:47)
    at g (events.js:180:16)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (c:\var\www\beta.com\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:77:12)
    at g (events.js:180:16)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\var\www\beta.com\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:118:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
{ [MongoError: server localhost:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'server localhost:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}' }
{ [MongoError: server localhost:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'server localhost:27017 received an error {"name":"MongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}' }
```

**Schema**

```
var GameScheme = new Schema({
    fixtureID: String,
    date: Date,
    home_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Clubs', default: null },
    away_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Clubs', default: null },
    year: String,
    season_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Seasons' },
    siteID: String,
    leagueID: String,
    league_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Leagues', default: null },
    result: {type: Array, default: null},
    venue: {type: String, default: null},
    venue_id: {type: String, default: null},
    postponed: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    mayfield: {type: Boolean, default: false}
})
```

Of course I would like to know how to stop this error, but there isn't enough data for me to understand the real problem.

I have read that it might be the size of the db, however on this particular `Model` has only 6 rows currently. So I am not sure but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Is a `mongod` process running on `localhost:27017`? You should be able to execute `mongo` to bring up the shell.

Comment: This error is not related with your node.js codes. Check the mongo logs what causes this issue. Btw did you try restart mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the error because I had copied over the following files whilst trying to make a complete backup of the DB:

```
data
  ¬ db
    ¬ mays.0
    ¬ mays.ns
```

Once I repaired the db all was good with the world once again.

Comment: Do you mean a restore of a backup (being performed at the same time as an access)?

Answer (score 0):

```
  ...
  league_id: null,
  away_id: null,
  home_id: null },
{ _id: 56083f1b9a1b20d88c3c3e06,
  mayfield: false,
  postponed: false,
  ...
```

Please note the comma (,) after closing brace.

Comment: Unfortunately it is just a sample. This is taken from my `console.log`. But thank you for pointing it out :)